# mysql remove the `CR` or `0D` from text field when export the data set to a csv file

Tags: mysql, csv, format, export

This issue is related to the line change of export csv file. I have a result table and I want to export it to save as a csv file,but I'm not satisfied with the export format especially for the line change:

**Original table showed in mysql workbench**
[image: data set in workbench]

**The output csv file**
[image: output csv file]
as you can see, each record change a line after the column of `transfer_fee`, and below is my code for export

```
(select 'id','player_id','season','before_date','before_value','transfer_date',
'transfer_fee','after_date','after_value')
union
(select * 
from market_value_variation
into outfile 'E:/Equipment/PythonWorkSpace/MarketValue/sql/market_value_variation.csv'
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n');
```

and this problem remains if I use the export function of mysql workbench and the result limit to 1000 for workbench btw.
I wonder how I can get a result just change lines each record in the out put csv file like:

```
id,player_id,season,before_date,before_value,transfer_date,transfer_fee,after_date,after_value
1,192565,15/16,2015-07-01,3400000,2015-07-01,-,2015-07-01,3400000
2,139278,15/16,2015-07-01,150000,2015-07-01,-,2015-07-01,150000
3,153628,15/16,2015-07-01,128000,2015-07-01,-,2015-07-01,128000
4,143121,15/16,2015-07-01,425000,2015-07-01,-,2015-07-01,425000
5,165007,15/16,2015-07-01,10200000,2015-08-28,End of loan,2016-02-22,10200000
...
```

I have tried `\r\n` already but this issue remains and it's weird that each record after transfer_fee got a `\` at the end of the first line,for instance:

```
id,player_id,season,before_date,before_value,transfer_date,transfer_fee,after_date,after_value
1,192565,15/16,2015-07-01,3400000,2015-07-01,-\
,2015-07-01,3400000
2,139278,15/16,2015-07-01,150000,2015-07-01,-\
,2015-07-01,150000
3,153628,15/16,2015-07-01,128000,2015-07-01,-\
,2015-07-01,128000
```

---

after check the value of `transfer_fee` by either code:

```
select hex(transfer_fee) from market_value_variation;
```

or `Open Value in Editor` in mysql workbench,I found that the hex value of `transfer_fee` is `2D0D`, and the `0D` means `CR` which is the carriage return,then I tried several methods suggested on stackoverflow of other same issues like:

```
update market_value_variation set transfer_fee=trim(trailing '\n' from transfer_fee);
update market_value_variation set transfer_fee=replace(transfer_fee,'\r\n','');
update market_value_variation set transfer_fee=replace(transfer_fee,'\n','');
update market_value_variation set transfer_fee=trim('\r\n' from transfer_fee);
update market_value_variation set transfer_fee=trim('\n' from transfer_fee);
```

but they did't work for me,the issue remains like:

[image: 2D0D]

or in text format

[image: 2d0d]

so I wonder how I can remove the `CR` or `0D` from `transfer_fee`?

and I work on window 10 OS with mysql 5.7.11

Any help is appreciated,thank you.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a problem with your actual text editor's presentation of the data.  Have you tried using a different edtitor?  Also, you can use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'`, since you are on Windows.

Comment: Well,I have tried '\r\n'  already but this issue remains and it's wired that each record after `transfer_fee` got a `\` at the end of the first line ,for instance 
...
`1,192565,15/16,2015-07-01,3400000,2015-07-01,-\
,2015-07-01,3400000`
...

Comment: I think you may have line breaks in some of your `transfer_fee` values.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen,maybe you're right, I try `select hex(transfer_fee) from market_value_variation;` and got a result as `2D0D`,but I wonder how I can handle this issue?

Comment: What does `hex` have to do with this?  Check your columns for line breaks.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen ,well, I use `hex` to show the `CR` in the text field, you're right that I have a `carriage return` in the text field and I just updated my question and try to remove the `CR` and finally solved it, you may get the detail information according to my new version of question and my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Finally,the direct way to solve this problem is to write

```
update market_value_variation 
set transfer_fee=replace(replace(transfer_fee,'\n',''),'\r','');
```

which removes the `0d` in text field and it works for the final export csv file.

Comment: Good idea. I had a similar issue and so I did a SQL `REPLACE` on the newlines before exporting, and then turned them back into newlines on the other end. Thanks.